# Can you inspect elements in outlook?

Tags: html, email, html-email, email-client

i am developing HTML emails and no wonder, making it good on outlook is painstakingly challenging.
is there any way you can inspect elements on outlook the way we usually do on browser console?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to use a tool like Litmus or Email on Acid. You can send your code to lots of different environments, and then get screenshots - and resultant code - back.

In Litmus, in an email, you go to Builder -> Email Previews -> Outlook preview -> View processed HTML. It will give you a render & the final code.

While you can view the source in Outlook (see PaulS answer: Open email (double-click) > Actions > Other Actions > View Source), that gives you the source, which you already have. To get the rendered code, you can forward your email to yourself, and then go to view source. It will have a little bit extra at the top, but should be essentially the translated HTML.

Then, once you have the code, you can copy that to a new HTML file and open that up in Chrome/FF/your browser.

However, this is not particularly helpful. That's for advanced use-cases. If you stick to simple tables and inline CSS, and leave out HTML5 and CSS3, you'll be pretty much right.

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft Outlook, double-click to open an email. You’ll see an “Actions” menu under the “Message” tab. Click on that menu and select the “Other Actions,” then click on “View Source” to see the HTML code.

Comment: That will grab the *source* but not what it's translated to within Outlook

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, no.
There are ways to grab the source code using the steps @PaulS detailed.

I would also look into reading 'how-to code for Outlook' articles. Plenty of them out there and they'll give you an idea of where you could add Outlook only code to make your layouts work as they do in other email clients or simply learn how to adjust/adapt your code to work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The steps PaulS Detailed are for Versions  2010 < X < 365.   As the world will be exclusively 365 by October 2023, nobody will have an "Actions" menu.

this implies that Microsoft would like to eliminate code insertion or any other means of HTML code manipulation by users.

https://www.msoutlook.info/question/insert-html-code-directly-into-an-email